# C# EF throw SQL error 26 from created AppDomain

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I can't figure out why below source code throws an exception

```
using (var ctx = new DBContext())
{
    var t= ctx.Objs.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == 0);
}
```

SQL exception is:

> provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

It occurs only if I called this code from manually created `AppDomain`:

```
_domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestAppDomain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, 
                new AppDomainSetup()
                {
                    ApplicationBase = MyDir
                });

_domain.ExecuteAssemblyByName("MyClassName")
```

If I call method from `MyClassName` directly, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the AppDomain you create have its own .config file?

Comment: Yep. In other case EF could't be supported (entityFramework tag and so on)

Comment: and the connection strings are identical?

Comment: Wow. Thx a lot! I missed that and after fix it's working. Btw is it possible to external configure MyClassName assembly to use it's own .config while it's created with AppDomain?